# JAXB is good until I need to do something complex. What are the alternatives?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

JAXB works well until I need to do something like serialize beans for which I cannot modify the source. If the bean doesn't have a default constructor or if it refers to objects I want to mark transient then I'm stuck writing a separate bean which I can annotate and then manually copy the information over from the other bean.

For instance, I wanted to serialize exception objects, but found that the only way to do that was use a hack that required using com.sun.* classes.

So, what alternatives are there? What's the next most popular xml serializing api? It would be nice to be able to do things like:

- Choose at serialization time whether to include certain fields in the result. (marking things transient when running the serializer).
- Handle loops in the object graph by using references or something other than just dying.
- Perhaps annotate an object so that in version 1 it serializes things in one way and in version 2 it serializes them in another. Then when serializing I just choose which version of the object ot serialize.
- Have a way to generate XSDs from annotations on an object.

Basically I just want more flexibility than I currently have with JAXB.

Answer (score 2):

JAXB is a spec, so you can pick from different implementations.  [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) has extensions for what you are asking:

**Externalized Metadata**

Useful when dealing with classes for which you cannot annotate the source or to apply multiple mappings to an object model.

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/EclipseLink-OXM.XML

**XPath Based Mapping**

For true meet-in-the-middle OXM mapping:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/MOXyExtensions

**JPA Compatibility**

Including support for bi-directional relationships.

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/jpa-entities-to-xml-bidirectional.html
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JPA

Answer (score 1):

Also look at JIBX. It's a good xml<->object mapper. My experience is though that if your objects have a somewhat funky relationships it's often easier to create a wrapper object that hides that complexity and then map that object with JIBX.